# Boolean simplification of y(x' + (x+y)')

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've been trying to perform Boolean simplification on the following expression: $y(x' + (x+y)')$

So far, my steps have been:

> $y(x' + (x+y)')$
>
> $y(x' + x'y')$
>
> $y(x' + x')(x' + y')$
>
> $(yx')(x' + y') $

I have no idea where to go from here. I feel as if I've complicated this.
I know the end result is supposed to be $x'y$.

Comment: I believe your third step there is where you are going off target.

Comment: @IntegrateThis The third step is valid (it's an instance of Distibution) ... but indeed not helpful

Answer (score 1):

$x' + x'y'$ simplifies to $x'$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what rule is used to simplify x' + x'y' to x'?

Comment: x' + x'y' = x' ( 1 + y') , and 1+ y' is always true

Comment: But also, consider the truth table. It's obvious I think.

Comment: @Derrin The rule for this is called Absorption.